# Error encountered when creating custom field in sugarcrm

Tags: exception, sugarcrm

I got the below warning while trying to create a custom field in sugarcrm.

```
Warning:

Creating default object from empty value in C:\xampp\htdocs\Sugarcrm\modules\ModuleBuilder\views\view.modulefield.php on line 151
{"east":{"title":"Edit Field","crumb":"","content":"
<\/div>\n\n
```

Answer (score 1):

Adjust your php.ini file to set display_errors=Off

I've seen this a few times and it usually comes from code-level customization, but not always. Either way, it's the PHP Notice/Warning/Error that's throwing off the AJAX response within Studio.

Answer (score 1):

This is caused by a newer version of PHP.

Add the following code after line 150 in **modules/ModuleBuilder/views/view.modulefield.php**

```
VardefManager::loadVardef($moduleName, $objectName,true);
global $dictionary;
// add the next three lines
if(!isset($module->mbvardefs) || is_null($module->mbvardefs)) {
     $module->mbvardefs = new stdClass();
}
```

Source: https://github.com/sugarcrm/sugarcrm_dev/pull/143/files