# SugarCRM on shared Dreamhost server: "Creating default object from empty value"

Tags: php, sugarcrm, dreamhost

I am using the latest version of SugarCRM on Dreamhost (version SugarCE-6.5.17).  All runs well, except for getting the following error when I try to add a field.

> Warning: Creating default object from empty value in /home/blastofflabs/sugar.blastofflabs.com/crm/modules/ModuleBuilder/views/view.modulefield.php on line 151
>   {"east":{"title":"Edit Field","crumb":"","content":"
>   </div>\n\n

At 2:08 of this YouTube video, you can see what it was that I was doing.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=atMeObDkGZI

**UPDATE**

*Dreamhost support suggests making a phprc file on the shared server*

I created that file, created a phprc file (per Dreamhost), added "dispay_errors=Off", and then ran "chmod 755" to give it the right permissions.

http://wiki.dreamhost.com/Creating_a_phprc_file

http://webmaster.iu.edu/upgrade/phprc.phtml

http://www.courtzabel.net/articles/2013/increasing-limits-php-dreamhost

http://www.askapache.com/php/custom-phpini-tips-and-tricks.html

Comment: Dup of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20920317/error-encountered-when-creating-custom-filed-in-sugarcrm - but you wouldn't have known since there was a typo in the post's title. Still marking as dup ;)

Comment: Ah, thanks.  Looks like I gotta modify that PHP.ini file.  I'll check with Dreamhost and see if that's even possible under a shared host.

Answer (score 0):

This is caused by a newer version of PHP.

Add the following code to after line 150 in **modules/ModuleBuilder/views/view.modulefield.php**

```
VardefManager::loadVardef($moduleName, $objectName,true);
global $dictionary;
// add the next three lines
if(!isset($module->mbvardefs) || is_null($module->mbvardefs)) {
     $module->mbvardefs = new stdClass();
}
```

Source: https://github.com/sugarcrm/sugarcrm_dev/pull/143/files